# Regular expression which accepts 0.5 and whole numbers

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces

Hi I need help on a regular expression which accepts only 0.5 and whole numbers. I try this but its not working: pattern="^[0.5][0-9]*"

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: `[0.5]` matches **one** of these three characters: `'0'`, `'.'`, `'5'`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following: `^0\.5|\d+$`. Just pay attention that in Java code you have to write duplicate back slashes, i.e. `Pattern.compile("0\\.5|\\d+$")`.

Back slash before `.` is required to make regex to understand that it is the character `.` and not "any character"